# How to mark some generated tests as xfail/skip?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

With py.test I often have generated tests where some test cases are expected to fail. How can I mark them as xfail? If I put the `@py.test.mark.xfail` on the test function it means all instances of it are xfail. If I do `py.test.xfail()` inside the test it actually fails the test, not just marks it as xfail. Is there something I can do with metafunc to add this marker?

e.g.

```
# code - function with a bug :)

def evenHigherThanSquare(n):
    return n**2


# test file

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    data = [
        (2, 4),
        (3, 10), # should be xfail
        (4, 16),
        (5, 26), # should be xfail
        ]
    for input, expected in data:
        if metafunc.function is test_evenHigherThanSquare:
            metafunc.addcall(funcargs=dict(input=input, expected=expected))


def test_evenHigherThanSquare(input, expected):
    assert evenHigherThanSquare(input) == expected
```

Comment: Looks complicated. Could it be rewritten using simpler approach? Like create one test with a list of values that should pass and a list of values that should fail.

Comment: @demalexx this example is overengineered for sure, but it's just intended to be a minimum working example. in my actual tests the test data and the test itself have a lot more going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, you can use a [funcarg factory](http://pytest.org/latest/funcargs.html) to [apply an xfail marker](http://pytest.org/latest/funcargs.html#_pytest.python.FuncargRequest.applymarker) [(since 1.3.2)](http://pytest.org/latest/changelog.html#changes-between-1-3-1-and-1-3-2):

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    data = [
        # input # output # is expected to fail?
        (2, 4, False),
        (3, 10, True),
        (4, 16, False),
        (5, 26, True),
        ]
    for input, expected, xfail in data:
        if metafunc.function is test_evenHigherThanSquare:
            metafunc.addcall(funcargs=dict(input=input, expected=expected),
                             param=xfail)


def pytest_funcarg__xfail(request):
    if request.param:
        request.applymarker(py.test.mark.xfail)


def test_evenHigherThanSquare(input, expected, xfail):
    assert evenHigherThanSquare(input) == expected
```

Here we're using the unused `xfail` parameter to `test_evenHigherThanSquare` to trigger the invocation of `pytest_funcarg__xfail` on each test item; it uses the `param` that was supplied to `metafunc.addcall` to decide whether to xfail the test.

Funcarg factories are more commonly used to generate arguments that are expensive to create at collection time, but applying markers is also a fully supported usage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```py
def evenHigherThanSquare(n):
    return n ** 2


# test file

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    data = [
        pytest.param(2, 4, marks=[]),
        pytest.param(3, 10, marks=[pytest.mark.xfail]),
        pytest.param(4, 16, marks=[]),
        pytest.param(5, 26, marks=[pytest.mark.xfail]),
    ]
    if metafunc.function is test_evenHigherThanSquare:
        metafunc.parametrize("input, expected", data)


def test_evenHigherThanSquare(input, expected):
    assert evenHigherThanSquare(input) == expected
```

Comment: It can also be used with `@pytest.mark.parametrize`: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/skipping.html#skip-xfail-with-parametrize